# Separate agency name and phone from address sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to separate city name from the addresses in the Data base.
In below format.

```
OrderId AgencyName Phone
1234    Test       (788) 888-8888
```

Table data are in below format.

```
OrderId   DataValue
1234      {"AgencyName":"Test","Phone":"(788) 888-8888","submit":false}
```

Comment: That's JSON data, not just a string. All SQL Server versions in mainstream support (2016+) are able to parse JSON strings

Comment: If you use an unsupported SQL Server version it's easier to parse the data on the client than try to use T-SQL for string parsing. T-SQL is *terrible* at that and doesn't even support regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have JSON values, then use `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
select orderid, 
    json_value(datavalue, '$.AgencyName') agencyname,
    json_value(datavalue, '$.Phone') phone
from mytable
```

Note that this requires SQL Server 2016 or higher.

Comment: Worth mentioning that 2016 is the oldest version still in mainstream support.

Answer (score 0):

For lower versions you can use -

```
with t as
(select 1234 as order_id,'{"AgencyName":"Test","Phone":"(788)-888-8888","submit":false}' value)
select order_id, substring(value,charindex(':',value,1)+2,patindex('%Phone%',value)-3-charindex(':',value,1)-2) as Agency, substring(value,charindex(':',value,15)+2,patindex('%submit%',value)-3-charindex(':',value,15)-2) as Phone  
from t ;
```